# How to select element from div with role = combobox in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My html code is:

```
<td class="v-formlayout-contentcell">
    <div role="combobox" class="v-filterselect v-widget v-required v-filterselect-required v-has-width v-filterselect-prompt" id="envRegulations" style="width: 255px;">
        <input type="text" class="v-filterselect-input" autocomplete="off" id="gwt-uid-366" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-365" aria-required="true" style="width: 100%;" tabindex="0" dir="">
        <div class="v-filterselect-button" aria-hidden="true" role="button"></div>
    </div>
</td>
<div class="v-filterselect-button" aria-hidden="true" role="button"></div>
```

In dropdown list are 2 values: "Yes" and "No"

I tried many variants (By.cssSelector, By.xPath) to force writing in this field but not working.
Last version of code:

```
WebElement environmentalRegulations = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("envRegulations")));
environmentalRegulations.sendKeys("YES");
environmentalRegulations.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Mention that id = "gwt-uid-366" is dynamic value and I can't get it.

How do I select a value from that div? Can you help me, please?

Comment: I don't see any dropdown values of Yes and No. Can you share the URL of the page so I can see for myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebElement environmentalRegulations = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("envRegulations")));`

change this line to point to the `input` rather the div as shown below
`WebElement environmentalRegulations = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#envRegulations input")));`

Comment: Done. I resolved with "By.cssSelector("#envRegulations input"))". Thank you! :)